# jquery dynamic form elements for spring form binding

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, spring2.x

I am facing issues with dynamically binding spring form elements in JSP using jquery. 
I am trying to add dynamic rows to a table which has different form elements. 
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ninadhere/f7ZdK/

Issue here is newly added form elements are havng id's & name attribute as "userName[0]1" instead of "userName[1]" hence they are not getting binded to spring form. I am using a AbstractWizardController and trying to binding Dynamic list of User's on Step1 and then using them in Step2.

Is their a way to systematically clone the form elements like dropdown, checkbox and text.

Can someone guide me on using this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass true while cloning the element will copy all event with the cloned element.

from http://api.jquery.com/clone/

> .clone( [withDataAndEvents] ) withDataAndEventsA Boolean indicating
>   whether event handlers should be copied along with the elements. As of
>   jQuery 1.4, element data will be copied as well.

Replacing integer value of id:

```
  id.replace(/\[\d*\]$/, "["+ i +"]")// will replace 'userName[0]' with userName[{i}]
```

Comment: well here i dont need to copy element data i want to make sure the secure of dynamic form elements is generated correctly right now when I clone <input name="userName[0]"/> its get clone as **<input name="userName[0]1"/>** instead of **<input name="userName[1]"/>**

Comment: Thanks Shusl seems to work fine. Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ninadhere/f7ZdK/5/

Answer (score 0):

I have performed things like this before its quite tricky and you need to have full concentration while binding dynamic form field to the spring model.

Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614718/how-to-validate-dynamically-generated-fields-server-side)

Though my question is different but the code I have put in the question is what probably your answer. :)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Have you tried the same stuff in Spring 2.0.5 using AbstractWizardController ?

Comment: Nope. I have used it in Spring 3.0 only.