# spring:bind error using in a List

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a list containing users. I am trying to print it in JSP but some how I am not able to get it to print it. Getting this exception `HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'users[0]' available as request attribute`

Code in JSP

```
<c:forEach items="${users}" var="user" varStatus="status">
   <spring:bind path="users[${status.index}].name">
      <c:out value="${status.value}" />
   </spring:bind>
</c:forEach>
```

Controller

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("go_some_JSP_page");
List<UserEntity> users = userManager.getAllObjects();
modelAndView.addObject("users", users);
```

BTW, UserEntity has name field. If I remove the binding and try to print the `user.name` using `<c:out value="user.name" />` it prints the value

Where am I going wrong and what do I need to do? Thanks

Not working code below. [I have to invoke formatting on field @NumberFormat so have to try it using `status` variable]

```
<spring:bind path="user.name">
   <c:out value="${status.value}" />
</spring:bind>
```

Gets this error --> `javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute`

So added a bean binding and then I get empty table :(. I believe thats because the instance is empty. So this does not seems like a right approach.

```
@ModelAttribute("user")
public UserEntity userEntityBinding() {
    return UserEntity.newInstance();
}
```

A working code exists at https://github.com/hth/StatusInvoke.git

Let me know if you face any problem deploying it.

This question has been solved. Thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer to invoke @NumberFormat annotation is by using `spring:eval expression` tag

```
<spring:eval expression="user.balance" />
```

This invokes the annotation and performs formatting as mentioned in the annotation

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `LazyList` instead of simple list. If you want to take a look at the example then you can refer one of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614718/how-to-validate-dynamically-generated-fields-server-side). In the question statement I have mentioned how to use the LazyList.

Hope that helps you. Cheers.

Comment: I found the solution and the code is posted on github. A working code exists at https://github.com/hth/StatusInvoke.git

Comment: ok. I thought you want to bind the values of the list to the jsp controls. So I thought this would be more easy. :)

Answer (score 0):

this, if the modelandview are returned, is the correct way to populate the list

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("go_some_JSP_page");
List<UserEntity> users = userManager.getAllObjects();
modelAndView.addObject("users", users);
```

And this is the correct way to reference the list

```
<c:forEach items="${users}" var="user" varStatus="status">
    <spring:bind path="user.name">
      <c:out value="${status.value}" />
   </spring:bind>
</c:forEach>
```

Your problem must be elsewhere is the name field definitely populated, is the correct jsp being called... the above code is correct and should work.

Comment: userManager is not returning `user` empty. If I remove the binding and just print out the `user` it prints.

Comment: After changing the binding I see this error `javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute`

Comment: I assume you are asking what is the result of the code posted above :) Its actually blank. I see empty table. I have mentioned that in my posting. And the empty result is because of the empty object `UserEntity`

Comment: I have tried as you have mentioned and it still does not work. For reference I have created a sample code to test at https://github.com/hth/StatusInvoke.git

Comment: @java_dude you are redirecting from your index, to landing without actually calling the controller. Be sure to call your code using the url "/landing".

Comment: If the controller is not being called then how is the page being populated with data. Have you tried putting a break point in controller at ModelAndView?

Comment: @java_dude its not being populated with data, according to yr question

Comment: The data is getting populated but its not using `<spring:bind`. When you uncomment the `<spring:bind` at line 34 of `landing.jsp` you will see it failing.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. The reason why I have to get the uncommented section working is because the formatting code gets called through `var=status`. The UserEntity has @NumberFormat annotation and that would be called through `status` alone. If I print balance without status, then annotation would not be invoked and no formatting would show up.  Hope this clears it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use spring:bind in that case, AFAIK it tries to get the variable from the ModelMap, it's not able to get it from the "for" var.

Comment: Can you give more information as I am not able to understand what you are suggesting as alternative